# REST to update list item by Id

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

all is done, but please any one help me to update list item. i have called update function where it need to, but dont have update function. can any one please give me update function according to my variable, names, and code?

HTML:

```
 `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://instantdk.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/sticky_note.css">
<h2> Sticky Notes </h2>
<br />




<textarea rows="7" cols="50" id="StickyText" >

</textarea>

<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Save"  />
<ul id="list">

</ul>

 <script src='https://instantdk.sharepoint.com/Style Library/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>
<script src='https://instantdk.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/sticky_note.js'></script>
`
```

JS:

```
var listName = "StickyNotes";
var newItemTitle = "";
    var url = "https://instantdk.sharepoint.com/teamsite";

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    var new_task = $('#StickyText').val();
    $('#list').append('<li>'+new_task+'</li>');
    AddData()
});
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");

}
function AddData() {
    newItemTitle = $("#StickyText").val();
    addListItem(url, listName , newItemTitle)
}

// CREATE Operation
// listName: The name of the list you want to get items from
// weburl: The url of the web that the list is in. 
// newItemTitle: New Item title.
// success: The function to execute if the call is sucesfull
// failure: The function to execute if the call fails


function addListItem(url, listname, metadataName) {
    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listname);
    var taskProperties = {
        '__metadata': { 'type': itemType },
        'Title': metadataName
    };

    createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, listname, taskProperties)
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log('Task has been created successfully');
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
function createListItem(webUrl, listName, itemProperties) {
    return getFormDigest(webUrl).then(function (data) {

        return $.ajax({
            url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
            }
        });
    });
}

function getFormDigest(webUrl) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",   
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    });
}
// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}


//keep saving data in local storage
$(document).ready(function(){
    getMyListItems(url, listName);
});

function UpdateData(id){

}
  // READ SPECIFIC ITEM operation
// itemId: The id of the item to get
// listName: The name of the list you want to get items from
// siteurl: The url of the site that the list is in. 
// success: The function to execute if the call is sucesfull
// failure: The function to execute if the call fails
function getListItemWithId(query) {
    var Weburl = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items"+query ;
    $.ajax({
        url: Weburl ,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.results.length >= 1) {
                $('#StickyText').val();
                $("#StickyText").focusout(function(){
                    alert("saved with focusout.");
                    var new_task = $('#StickyText').val();
                    $('#list').append('<li>'+new_task+'</li>');
                    if(data.d.results[0] != null){
                        for(var i=0; i< data.d.results.length; i++){
                            UpdateData(data.d.results[i].Id);
                        }       
                    }                   

                });

            }
            else{
                $("#StickyText").focusout(function(){
                    alert("saved with focusout.");
                    var new_task = $('#StickyText').val();
                    $('#list').append('<li>'+new_task+'</li>');
                    AddData();

                });

            }
         },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}

function getCurrentUser(complete, failure)
{    
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/currentUser",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data.d); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
function getMyListItems(url, listName) {
  getCurrentUser(
    function(user){
       var query = '?$filter=AuthorId eq ' + user.Id; 
       getListItemWithId(query)   
     },
    function(error){
       alert(error);
     }  
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please refer the below code for update item using REST. 
Please try this code. Hope this work for you.

```
function UpdateData(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" +id+ ")",
        type: "PATCH",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-Http-Method": "PATCH",
            "If-Match": oldItem.__metadata.etag
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        success: function (data) {
            //success callbak
        },
        error: function (error) {
            //error callback
        }
    });
}
```